# Detecting when there have been changes in mysql db and reset db every 30 mins

Tags: mysql5

I'm junior dev with little experience. I have  a portfolio website with some examples of my work. As with many web applications, there's a login. I want to be able to publish the login credentials but have the database reset every half an hour if it's changed. This is to roll back the changes the user has made. As soon as I've published the credentials it maybe abused.  The web app is written in php using Symfony

Am too sure how I should go about doing this?